How to disable the "CORS policy execution successful" log message in ASP
We have a C#/ASP app which has a log with tons of entries like this:

CORS policy execution successful

Is there a way to disable this message?

That message comes from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService so you could just add that as an exclusion

@DavidG, will try that, thanks.
